# jQuery UI - Rotate, drag, resize DIV like in image editor

Tags: jquery-ui, rotation, resizable

I need "user-friendly" rotate, drag and resizable DIV. But, when this DIV is rotated, RESIZE function works very wierd. Not like in image editor. User can not handle resize properly. How to make it ?

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/wuw7xxj4/)

HTML :

```
<div id="blue"></div>
```

CSS :

```
#blue {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#blue").resizable({
    aspectRatio: false,
    handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
});

$("#blue").draggable();
```

Answer (score 8):

Worked on a similar Question: [How to get four corners rotate handle for a rotatable div..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460183/how-to-get-four-corners-rotate-handle-for-a-rotatable-div)

In this, OP wanted to add rotation handles to each corner. But it's a good example of what you're reporting too.

Take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7zc36sug/

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Wrapping the box helps out for Draggable.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  // Assign Draggable
  $('.box-wrapper').draggable({
    cancel: ".ui-rotatable-handle"
  });
  // Assign Rotatable
  $('.box').resizable().rotatable();
});
```

Resizing when at a rotated angle changes the location of the box, it's width and height, and causes it to move in a sort of weird way. This is why it does not work like it might in some graphics programs.

Since you did not indicate what you would prefer the behaivor to be like, I cannot properly answer your question: *User can not handle resize properly. How to make it?*

I hope this helps explain the issue.

Comment: For me saying .rotatable(); is not a function

Comment: Did you add the rotatable library? It's not part off jquery hi itself, it's a plug in.